# Formatting output XML from XMLQuery() in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery, formatting

I am using XMLQuery() to execute some XQuery in my tables that consists of records with XML documents (Oracle's XMLTYPE). The Oracle query looks like this:

```
SELECT XMLQuery(
'for $b in distinct-values($rdoc//book_title)
 let $r := $rdoc//review[book_title=$b]/rating
 order by avg($r) descending
 return 
  <book>
    <title>{data($b)}</title>
    <avgrating>{avg($r)}</avgrating>
  </book>'
passing b.data as "bdoc", r.data as "rdoc"
RETURNING CONTENT).getStringVal() XMLData
FROM books b, reviews r
```

I am getting the correct results but the SQLDeveloper shows me the results in a single line and not formated as an XML! I have noticed that if i have a query that is not using distinct-values() then the results appear properly.

Has anyone had the same issue and found a solution/workaround? I am on Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XMLSerialize function:

```
SELECT
  XMLSerialize(content XMLQuery(...your expression...) indent size=2) XMLData
FROM
  books b, reviews r
```

Just to be sure what you are doing, read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions252.htm#SQLRF06231